# IntelliSense and browsing information will not be available for C++ projects

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, intellisense

In Visual Studio trying to create a blank C++ project `Win32 Console Application` my app Settings are

- Console application
- Check empty project
- Precompiled headers is unchecked

Visual Studio tries to set it all up and then gives me the follow error:

[image]

Everything works except project has zero IntelliSense.

Here is what I tried so far:

1. I tried to install latest version of Microsoft SQL Server Compact 4.0 it keeps telling me the version you are trying to install is an older version and the one I have - is the latest.
2. There was something about Fallback Location setting it to true, tried that still the same.
3. Tried to run VS in admin mode, the same error.

Maybe someone had similar problem?

Comment: Delete the file maybe and see if it generated again when you restart VS?

Comment: @Golazo `ConsoleApplication1.opensdf` this is the file that is being generated but that file only exist when the project is in Visual Studio when visual studio is closed that file is gone and re-created again when project is open with the same error.

Comment: The presence of "FallbackLocation" in that directory path is quite unhealthy.  You need to create your project in a directory that Visual Studo can easily write to and reliably lock files in.  It for example should not be located on a memory stick.

Comment: If I was you, I'd reinstall VS all components enabled

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem too. I figured out my problem by install Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5 Service Pack 2 for Windows Desktop.  The link is https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?displaylang=en&id=5783
May it can help you with your problem. good luck

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem and solved it by starting *Visual Studio* as **administrator**.

The problem appeared, because I had previously started Visual Studio as **admin**, and the *Debug Folder* it created wasn't writable then for the **normal** user.

**Otherwise**: deletion of the *Debug folder* would presumably also have fixed the problem.